# Element does not obey overflow hidden when a child element is animated in from outside the overflow area with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a page which has a hidden form, which should animate into view when a link is clicked. This was achieved by absolutely placing the form outside of the container, giving the container a position of relative, and then animating the form into view on it's top position.

**The problem:**

When I click on the link, the form shows up underneath the container content, pushing the content up and seemingly ignoring the "overflow: hidden" property.

The form then animates up creating a strange effect. It should neatly animate over the content as if appearing from the bottom of the `div` without affecting the container content whatsoever.

Please see **[this jsFiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Efv/1/)**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="theContainer">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>

<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores erat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et um dolor sit amet..</p> <a class="showForm" href="#show-form" title="Show the form">Show the form!</a>

<div class="theForm">
     <h2>The Form</h2>
    <p>Slitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
     <input autofocus="autofocus" max_length="255" type="text" name="email" id="id_email" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.theContainer {
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 460px;
}
.theForm {
    display: none;
    background: pink;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var theContainer = $('.theContainer'),
        theContainerHeight = theContainer.height(),
        theForm = $('.theForm'),
        theLink = $('.showForm');

    theContainer.css({
        'height': theContainerHeight + 'px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'position': 'relative'
    });

    theForm.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': theContainerHeight + 'px'
    });

    theLink.click(function () {
        theForm.css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        theForm.animate({
            'top': '0'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: In my browser, the jsFiddle is acting like you want. The form is sliding over the content without any strange effects. (Firefox 22)

Comment: The problem only occurs in Chrome. As David Hedlund pointed out, this is because the input field automatically gain focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the input field automatically gains focus when it's shown (at least in Chrome; in browsers that don't do this, you won't have this issue), causing the div to scroll down to the element that would be hidden by the `overflow: hidden`, had the div been scrolled to the top.

Manually adding `theContainer.scrollTop(0);` to your click function avoids the issue:

```
theLink.click(function () {
    theForm.show().animate({'top':0}, 1000);
    theContainer.scrollTop(0);
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9YbAB/)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works perfectly, I'll add the amended JS code in here for extra clarity.

Answer (score 1):

css

```
.theContainer {
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 460px;overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.theForm {
    display: none;
    background: pink;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var theContainer = $('.theForm'),
        theContainerHeight = theContainer.height(),
        theForm = $('.theForm'),
        theLink = $('.showForm');

    theContainer.css({
        'height': theContainerHeight + 'px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'position': 'relative'
    });

    theForm.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
            'top': theContainerHeight + 'px'
    });

    theLink.click(function () {
        theForm.css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        theForm.animate({
            'top': '-0px'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a link to an amended/working jsFiddle, along with some explanation of the modifications you made.